# Problems with creeping line on the site

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Good day.
I want to implement a running line with text and a picture on the site.
I have been suffering for a long time with the implementation itself.
Came in a result when the line runs fine but breaks off at the end and starts over.
The idea is that the line should not break and move with infinite spaces.
Below I am attaching the code

html

```
  <div class="line-block">

    <div class="line__wrapper">
      <p class="line__text">Marketplace <br> Leader</p>
      <img src="images/general/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="line__img">
    </div>

    <div class="line__wrapper">
      <p class="line__text">Marketplace <br> Leader</p>
      <img src="images/general/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="line__img">
    </div>

    <div class="line__wrapper">
      <p class="line__text">Marketplace <br> Leader</p>
      <img src="images/general/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="line__img">
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="line-block">

    <div class="line__wrapper">
      <p class="line__text">Marketplace <br> Leader</p>
      <img src="images/general/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="line__img">
    </div>

    <div class="line__wrapper">
      <p class="line__text">Marketplace <br> Leader</p>
      <img src="images/general/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="line__img">
    </div>

    <div class="line__wrapper">
      <p class="line__text">Marketplace <br> Leader</p>
      <img src="images/general/logo.svg" alt="logo" class="line__img">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

sass

```
.line-infinite
  margin: 30px auto
  padding: 30px 0px
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-between
  align-items: center
  border-top: 1px solid #fff
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff
  overflow: hidden
  div
    width: 200%
    display: flex
    justify-content: space-between
    animation: runline 5s linear infinite

.line__block
  width: 100%

.line__wrapper
  min-width: 33%
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-between
  align-items: center

.line__text
  font-size: 32px
  line-height: 36px
  text-align: center
  margin: 0px 50px

.line__img
  width: 200px

@keyframes runline
  0%
    transform: translateX(0%)
  100%
    transform: translateX(-50%)
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] please?

Comment: https://youtu.be/oHXDJ_CT660 Here's a video. Here you can see that the creeping line goes well and breaks off at the end, and it is in this break that the problem lies. According to the idea, it should go unbroken and uninterrupted

Comment: Please read [mcve] video is not usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the animation property you put on the `div` insert forwards at the end of the animation or type: `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` in the `div` element you can find more about `animation-fill-mode` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) reply to me if you have any more problems